# Running FFMpeg on the server (to save the user from waiting)

Tags: php, html, video, ffmpeg

I have made a simple page that lets a user upload videoes for then to display all the videoes uploaded using the `HTML5 <video>` tags. But to provide the user with full browser support I need to transcode all the videoes that are being uploaded into a few new formats. The problem is then that now I am transcoding all vidoes into two different formats, which in turn takes a long time and it makes the user have to wait for the video being transcoded. Is there a simple way that anyone know of that lets me run this script in "the background" so that the user experience is in no way being compromised with long wait times?

I am running the `FFMpeg` scripts using `PHP` with the `exec` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are steps to achieve this.

```
1. First enter videos into a queue table.
2. Setup a cron to transcode videos after small interval like after every 5-10 minutes.
3. Make a section to show status of videos transcode for user. You can also use javascript periodicalexecuter for repeat check and show status somewhere on your page.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job and do it in background. Also if you are using FPM you can use fastcgi_finish_request()

Answer (score 1):

You can run processes in the background, so that your php script will not wait for finishing the new process. You can use this example:

```
<?
$command = "/usr/bin/php4 -f /var/www/myweb/start_ffmpeg.php";
exec( $command." > /dev/null &", $arrOutput );
?>
```

Found here: http://www.sitecrafting.com/blog/to-run-php-code-in/